# How to reorder fields in an ORBEON Form

Tags: orbeon

I understand that the layout in Orbeon Forms is grid-based, but even inside a grid of let's say 10 rows and 5 columns, If I happen to want to shift the 8th row to the 3rd row using the Visual Form Builder, how would I do that?

In general, is it possible to reorder the fields or sections within the Orbeon Designer using the MOUSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot reorder grid rows or columns, with or without a mouse (if by that you mean using drag-and-drop. But it's a great [suggestion](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=316180&group_id=168&atid=350207) for the Orbeon Forms authors.

At this point, what you can do is this:

- insert a new empty row
- using the toolbox, "cut" the first control you want to move
- using the toolbox, "paste" into the first cell of the new row
- repeat the last 2 steps

It's painful but it will work.

Or, you can move the row directly within the source of the form, by moving the  in the grid to the new place.

Note that while drag-and-drop would be great, it's not actually strictly needed: [buttons and keyboard shortcuts](http://blog.orbeon.com/2011/08/dealing-with-nested-sections-in-form.html) can get you there too.